# Help with the ffmpeg

Tags: vb6, cmd, ffmpeg, execute, frame-rate

I can read now the last line from the FFmpeg procees executed in a cmd window.
with this source using Scripting host model object reference.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim oExec       As WshExec
    Dim sRow        As String

    With New WshShell
        Set oExec = .Exec("ffmpeg.exe")
    End With
    Do While oExec.Status = WshRunning
        sRow = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
    Loop
End Sub
```

This line is like this. it's the last line in the cmd window (in the botom).

```
frame= 2816 fps=667 q=11.0 Lsize= 13036kB time=187.66 bitrate= 569.1kbits/s
```

I cut the part of Time to bulid a progress bar in my vb 6.0 app.  But in the cmd process exist a value 13 lines up this value its called Total duration.  But i cant read this line , somebody haves a code or any idea to read this line ubicated 13 lines up from the last line of the cmd window from ffmpeg...

Comment: I read all of it, but understood none of it. I thought I did, but I didn't. Weird.

Comment: **It is programming related**, kids.  Keep your finger off the close button and actually read the question.  Yes, it is hard...Ramses1974's English is not so good, but that is no excuses for your laziness.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this myself in Java.  I think the problem is that the status update lines (like you quote above with the `time=` substring) is terminated with a CR (Carriage Return) and not a LF (Line Feed).  My gut says that ReadLine is looking for a full CRLF.  So, to do this, you will need to:

- understand the difference between CR, LF and CRLF, and what ASCII code each is
- read in the output stream character by character, building up a CR-terminated line, and then parse it for the `time=` and `Durration=` tokens

It would help both you and us if you had debugging print statements in your code, and showed us the output.